# How to export an excel chart like this one?

Tags: c#, excel, charts, export-to-excel, series

I've been searching for 2 days now and I am running out of time and patience. I need to export chart in excel that looks like this:

[image]

I got kind of close but cant find out how to add the thresholds, change the color and size of the points nor add gridlines. The MSDN documentation is as vague as it can be.

I could really use some help, I am working in C#.

Comment: How close were you? What have you tried?

Comment: made an array of threshold values and added it to a serie but that is stupid and doesn't look the same

Comment: Never done that before TBH but I guess this link can point you to the right direction http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-chart.htm to go from there

Comment: that link is very basic and saw it long ago